# QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor() always returns 0 id

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-index

I'm creating a set of features and adding them to a QgsSpatialIndex to find the ones closest to a certain location.

Why does nearestNeighbor() always return [0L] instead of the correct feature id?

```
import random 

index = QgsSpatialIndex()

for i in range(0,10):
    feat = QgsFeature()
    pt = QgsPoint(
        random.randint(0,10),
        random.randint(0,10))
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt))
    index.insertFeature(feat)

nearest = index.nearestNeighbor(QgsPoint(5,5),1)
print nearest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Features only get an ID once they are added to a layer, but you can assign an ID manually using `QgsFeature.setFeatureId(int)` ([in QGIS 2.18 and earlier](http://qgis.org/api/2.14/classQgsFeature.html#a23becdfa7b1d399e705deb5f4c48ca19)) or `QgsFeature.setId(int)` ([in newer versions](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#ab1539bb160a37239afc57779e7cf9686)) (Thanks to ndawson for the pointer!):

```
import random 

index = QgsSpatialIndex()

for i in range(0,10):
    feat = QgsFeature()
    pt = QgsPoint(
        random.randint(0,10),
        random.randint(0,10))
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt))
    feat.setFeatureId(int)
    index.insertFeature(feat)

nearest = index.nearestNeighbor(QgsPoint(5,5),1)
print nearest
```

Alternatively, you can add the features to a memory layer:

```
import random 

index = QgsSpatialIndex()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()

for i in range(0,10):
    feat = QgsFeature()
    pt = QgsPoint(
        random.randint(0,10),
        random.randint(0,10))
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt))
    pr.addFeatures([feat]) 

index = QgsSpatialIndex(vl.getFeatures())
nearest = index.nearestNeighbor(QgsPoint(5,5),1)
print nearest
```

Comment: If your features aren't part of a layer you can manually assign feature IDs using QgsFeature.setId.

Comment: Thanks @ndawson! In 2.18 it seems to be QgsFeature.setFeatureId(int)